# How to enable ApiKeyRequired for an Api Method?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless, aws-sam-cli

I want to use the standard API Keys feature of API Gateway. If I use standard cloudformation this is possible by setting the property ApiKeyRequired to true for a method. How can I do this with SAM?

I tried using swagger but that does not seem to work:

```
    swagger: "2.0"
    info:
      title: !Ref AWS::StackName

    paths:
      "/machines/{resourceid}":
        get:
          parameters: 
            - name: resourceid 
              in: path 
              type: string 
              required: true 
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
            httpMethod: POST
            type: aws_proxy
            uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${MyLambda.Arn}/invocations
            responses: {}
          security:
            - authorizer: []

    securityDefinitions:
      authorizer:
        type: apiKey
        name: Authorization
        in: header
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

The following swagger definition works:

```
  DefinitionBody:
    swagger: "2.0"
    info:
      title: !Ref AWS::StackName
    x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source : "HEADER"
    paths:
      "/machines/{resourceId}":
        get:
          parameters: 
            - name: resourceId 
              in: path 
              type: string 
              required: true 
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
            httpMethod: POST
            type: aws_proxy
            uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${MessagingServiceTestHandler.Arn}/invocations
            responses: {}
          security:
            - api_key: []                      
    securityDefinitions:
      api_key:
        type: "apiKey"
        name: "x-api-key"
        in: "header"
```

The name of the api key header must be **x-api-key** rather than the standard Authorization header.

Comment: Hi @user3492652 , i had similar issue could you help me on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936126/how-to-enable-apikeyrequired-property-in-sam

Comment: Yea it enabled the API key, but not I got forbidden every time